# Select rows appearing after a row with a given ID when sorted by criteria unrelated to the ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord

Given the data in the table "people":

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Jane  |
|  2 | Joe   |
|  4 | John  |
|  5 | Alice |
|  6 | Bob   |
+----+-------+
```

And the order:

```
SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY name
```

... which would return:

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  5 | Alice |
|  6 | Bob   |
|  1 | Jane  |
|  2 | Joe   |
|  4 | John  |
+----+-------+
```

How could one write a query--including the order above--which would return only rows after the one with a given id, e.g., if given an id of 1, it would return:

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  2 | Joe   |
|  4 | John  |
+----+-------+
```

To be clear, the id is variable and not known before hand.

An approach using commonly supported SQL would be great, but I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2 and ActiveRecord 3.2 if they have anything additional of use, e.g., OVER() and ROW_NUMBER().

[Edit] I'd previously showed the wrong desired result set, including the row with the given id. But, the result set, as described in the question, should only include rows *after* the given ID.

Answer (score 6):

```
select *
from people
where
    name >= (
        select name
        from people
        where id = 1
    )
    and id != 1
order by name
```

Comment: Nice and simple and addresses the result set I'd shown, unfortunately that result set didn't match the question I was asking--now corrected in the question.

Comment: Nice, that'd certainly cover the usual suspects and would work in my case where some fuzziness might be acceptable. If exactness were required, this solution might get tripped up if there were several rows with 'Jane' (or any value sorted by the DB's collation as equivalent) as the name, no? Anyway, +1 from me and thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

So far the simplest approach I've found for a situation where precision is needed, e.g., no missing or duplicate results across multiple calls with varying values for ID is to combine window functions and CTEs, as in:

```
WITH ordered_people AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS n
  FROM people
  ORDER BY name
)

SELECT * 
  FROM ordered_people
  WHERE n > (SELECT n FROM ordered_people WHERE id = 1)
  ORDER BY name
;
```